# Arrays in C: Function which shows whether or not an array contains a certain element

Tags: c, arrays, algorithm, search

so this is the first question ive ever done involving arrays and im a bit confused. The question we are given is: 
Write a function named find_elem which takes the following arguments:
~integer elem
~integer array 
~int size
with size being the array size, and elem the element you have to find in the array.

If elem is part of the array, return the first position of the element in the array. If elem is not part of the array return -1.

```
Test                                  Output

    int array[] = {4, 2, -6, -1};
    printf("%d", find_elem(4, array, 4));   0
    int array[] = {4, 2, -6, -1};
    printf("%d", find_elem(-4, array, 4));  -1
```

The Test column is what the computer automatically reads in and the Output column is what our function should produce.
The following is the code i have written so far, any help is greatly appreciated.

```
    #include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <math.h>

int find_elem(int elem, int array[], int size) {

   int i;

   for (i = 0; i <= size-1; i++) {

       if (array[i] == elem) {
           printf("%d",i);
       }
   }

   if (array[i] != elem) {
       printf("-1");
   }
   return 0;
}
```

Comment: Your `if (array[i] != elem)` after the loop goes out of bounds because `i==size`, so you have undefined behavior and the function would print twice on the first call (so either UB or you don't show all output).

Comment: Think: if you found a match, do you have to continue searching (continue the loop)? Think: if you do not have to continue searching, then what is the situation after the loop?

Answer (score 1):

lets walk through your code, with simple array {1,1,2} and look for element 1:

In the first loop iteration,the condition will be satisfied, the 0 will be printed.
We will then continue for the next element. Again, the condition will be satisfied, and 1 will be printed.
In the next (and last) iteration, the condition will not be satisfied, do nothing will be printed.
Then we go out of the loop.
array, at position 2, is not 1, so , yet again, condition will be satisfied, and -1 will be printed.

To top all this out, the coded will then return constant 0, and not the position...

So you will need to break out of the look, once your element is found, and return that position, of -1 if element is not found.

Answer (score 1):

I do not know who is the author of the assignment but it is evident that he is a very weak programmer.

For starters the order of the parameters should be the following: array, its size, the value that is checked.

As the array is not changed in the function then it should be declared with the qualifier `const`. In C sizes of objects are calculated as values having the type `size_t` instead of `int`. The type int is not large enough to contain sizes of arrays.

If the value is not found in an array then the function should return the size of the array that is the index beyond the valid range of indices.

Take into account that the function should not output any message. It is the caller of the function that decides whether to output a message and which message.

Also you should not use magic numbers like `4`.

Nevertheless if to follow the assignment then the function can be defined as it is shown in the demonstrative program.

```
#include <stdio.h>

int find_elem( int value, const int a[], int n )
{
    int i = 0;

    while ( i < n && a[i] != value ) i++;

    return i == n ? -1 : i;
}

int main(void) 
{
    int array[] = { 4, 2, -6, -1 };
    const int N = sizeof( array ) / sizeof( *array );
    int value = 4;

    printf( "%d\n", find_elem( value, array, N ) );

    value = -4;

    printf( "%d\n", find_elem( value, array, N ) );

    return 0;
}
```

Its output is

```
0
-1
```

Take into account that neither `<stdlib.h>` nor `<math.h>` is required because neither declaration from these headers is used in the program.

Answer (score 1):

thanks for all the help! Combining the tips you guys gave me with some youtube videos I managed to write a very concise function from scratch which works perfectly!

```
  int find_elem(int elem, int array[], int size)
{
    for( int i=0 ; i < size; i++) 
    {
        if(array[i] == elem) 
        {
            return i; 
        }

    }
    return -1; 
}
```

Thanks again!

Comment: So you are not going to accept any of the answers? Some of which have provided code whith hardly a noticable difference to this. An explanation what they are lacking but is covered by this code would make this decision more convincing.

Answer (score 0):

See the usage of 
[return](http://www.c-programming-simple-steps.com/return-statement.html)

If I will optimize your code;

```
for (i = 0; i < size; i++) {

   if (array[i] == elem) 
       return i;
}
```

in here, **"return"** will break the loop and return the index value of the array position which is matching with your **"elem"** value. With breaking the loop, once the program founds that

> array[i] == elem

is true, function will be terminated with returning a value. If the **"elem"** value is not in your array, then program will go out of loop and continutes to execute another code blocks. So that;

```
for (i = 0; i < size; i++) {

if (array[i] == elem) 
   return i;
}

return -1;
```

Returning -1 after the loop ends, will help you to reach your aim for having -1 as a result of not finding **"elem"** value in your array.

As an addition, for make you understand what was your fault:

1) You looped inside your array, but even if "elem" matches with some value in array, loop continued to look another indices of array.

2) Even "elem" will not match with any value in your array, after your loop ends, you tried to check;

```
if (array[i] != elem) {
   printf("-1");
}
```

But in this step, **"i"** was assigned a value  which is exceeding the bounds of your array by the for loop. Anyways, even it will not exceed the bounds, your way was wrong to check it.

Answer (score -1):

You can use return as soon as you find element inside loop, it will optimise your code.
Also if loop completed, it means element not found, so no need to check anything else

```
#include <stdio.h> 
#include <stdlib.h> 
#include <math.h> 
int find_elem(int elem, int array[], int size) {
 int i; 
 int flag=0;
for (i = 0; i <= size-1; i++) 
{ 
if (array[i] == elem) {
 printf("%d",i); 
return i;
}
}
printf("-1"); 
 return -1;
 }
```

Comment: Don't just blurt out code! Adding some text to describe how this code best answers the question will improve the long-term quality of the answer and help to prevent it from being deleted during review.

Comment: Thanks @NightOwl888, I added explaination, hope it's making more sense now

Answer (score -1):

Need not run for loop upto `<= size-1`. All elements are covered within `0 to < size`. Secondly, in if block(inside `for`) use a flag variable to determine that `ele` is found (use a break statement to stop further iterations) or not. Replace `(array[i] != elem)` with `(flag == 0) return 0;` i.e. not found.

And note that you are always printing once and returning 0 from function. Hence output will be printed twice. Rather than using `printf` in `find_ele` function just return either 1 or 0(Not found).